# how to create a solid object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i am working on a simple game but i am stuck i have created 2 squares one that you can move and the other is supposed to be impassable but i cant find the code to make it a solid object. i need this as the second square will be a shelf on which the 1st square (the player) will jump on. this is just the start that i came across this problem and this game is no where near finished as i can not figure out how to do this many thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Something fancy</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Arrow keys to move, and space to jump</h3>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <style>
 canvas{border:1px solid black;}
 </style>
 <script>
 (function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 800,
    height = 500,
 shelf = {
      x : width/20,
      y : height - 50,
      width : 60,
      height : 50
    };
    player = {
      x : width/2,
      y : height - 5,
      width : 50,
      height : 50,
      speed: 5,
      velX: 0,
      velY: 0,
      jumping: false
    },
    keys = [],
    friction = 0.8,
    gravity = 0.8;
 

 
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function update(){
  // check keys
    if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
        // up arrow or space
      if(!player.jumping){
       player.jumping = true;
       player.velY = -player.speed*2;
      }
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        // right arrow
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {
            player.velX++;
        }
    }
    if (keys[37]) {
        // left arrow
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
    }
   
    player.velX *= friction;
   
    player.velY += gravity;
  
    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;
    
    if (player.x >= width-player.width) {
        player.x = width-player.width;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {
        player.x = 0;
    }
  
    if(player.y >= height-player.height){
        player.y = height - player.height;
        player.jumping = false;
    }
  
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.fillStyle = " #BA004B";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
  
if(createjs.Bitmap.prototype.getBoundingRect == null){
    createjs.Bitmap.prototype.getBoundingRect = function(){
        return new createjs.Rectangle(
                this.x - this.image.width/2,
                this.y - this.image.height/2,
                this.image.width,
                this.image.height);
    }
}

if(createjs.Rectangle.prototype.intersects == null){
    createjs.Rectangle.prototype.intersects = function(rect){
        return (this.x <= rect.x + rect.width &&
                rect.x <= this.x + this.width &&
                this.y <= rect.y + rect.height &&
                rect.y <= this.y + this.height);
    }
}

    
 // draw a small red box, which will eventually become our block.
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 ctx.fillRect(shelf.x, shelf.y, shelf.width, shelf.height); 

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}



document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});


window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    update();
});



 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Read [Collision Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) and [2D Collision Detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection).

Comment: Nice start by the way.

Comment: Out of curiosity... are you working from a tutorial?

Comment: no i am not i am just looking for the direct code for collision

Comment: @morgan Both Brett and Barryrowe offered excellent resources on detecting collisions between two 2D objects. Give that an attempt, then write back with the code you've attempted.

Comment: @crush i am looked at all the links and i still haven't found it i want to make it so when the objects hit each other they stop moving but i can't find how to do that on the links sorry if i have missed it or something

Comment: There's no magic property that can be set to do this. You have to implement this functionality. You do that with math. All the links show the math to do this. The link from @Barryrowe even shows an example. Try something, and then post back the code you've tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: i have tried to add it in i am not that good at understanding javascript so i have tried any more advice you could give would be really appreciated thanks.(look at code above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are talking about implementing is Collision Detection code. There are different ways to implement collisions, and the "right" implementation will depend on your game's needs.

Here is a good resource that will get you over your current hurdle, and will let you continue forward. Just know that you'll want to build out some kind of collision detecting and resolving functions that will run over all of your "collidable" objects as you introduce more.

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/11/26/GameDev-math-recipes-Collision-detection-using-an-axis-aligned-bounding-box.aspx

To completely oversimplify basic collision detection:

1. Give your entities a shape and position
2. On each update/render loop:

   a. check if any of your entity shapes overlap
   b. Adjust the entities back to their previous position if they should not be overlapping.

Comment: Adding to this answer, to avoid a rubberbanding effect, it might be better to check if they WOULD overlap before actually moving them. To eliminate checking objects that aren't really in danger of being overlapped, look into some type of spatial structure that segregates objects into buckets - QuadTree is one of the best for 2D that I've used. You really only need such a structure if you are dealing with LOTS of objects.

Comment: sorry if i am annoying but i do not understand what you mean by this.

Comment: @morgan Looking at your updated code, you've started to implement to intersection code. You'll want to move the prototype definition outside of your update() method. You only want to define the prototype once. If your Rectangle class takes a position and width/height, Then you would do something like this on initialization (outside of update):
`player.collider = new Rectangle(px, pY, pWidth, pHeight);
shelf.collider = new Rectangle(sX, sY, sWidth, sHeight);`
  
then in update you would do:
    `if(player.collider.intersects(shelf.collider)){
         //Resolve collision here
    }`

Comment: thank you for this but do i have to remove anything from the code becuse it dosen't show the charactures when i add it in thank you anyway.

Comment: @morgan is your the code posted your exact code you're running locally? If so, you're referencing an object "createJs" that has not been defined. The example link I provided uses a library to simplify defining types. If you're not using the createJs library, you'll need to define your own Rectangle type and setup the prototype for "intersects" for it much like you already are doing. Keep at it, and keep learning about the language itself.  [javascript tutorials MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) You'll get there.